# Consulta sobre tablas no relacionadas

Tags: java, sql, jpa

Tengo una duda de como podría realizar la búsqueda de tablas que no están relacionadas en la `BD` pero si tienen relación. Tengo una tabla principal que son empleados:

```
public class empleados{
    private int  empleado;
    private int provincia;
    private int oficina;
}
```

Tengo otras dos tablas que son provincia (con el identificador que tengo en la tabla de empleados recogería en esa tabla el nombre de la provincia) y otra tabla que sabiendo el código de oficina en la tabla oficinas cogería el nombre. Quiero recoger los datos así:

```
select a.empleado , b.nombreProvincia, 
c.nombreOficina from empleados a 
from empleados a
left join provincias b on b.id_provincia = a.provincia,
left join oficinas c on c.id_oficina = a.oficina;
```

Es el primer caso que tengo de tablas no relacionadas entre ellas en la `BD` pero si que tienen relación(no puedo relacionarlas en la `BD` ya que esta así generadas). 
He utilizado siempre `Jpa Repository` pero siempre tenían relación entre ellas y ahora no se si se podría realizar con `Jpa Repository` o directamente hacer una `query` con `Criteria` y recoger la información. Porque con `Jpa Repository` lo que estoy recogiendo es el data de empleados pero como en este caso el data de empleados no seria ya que habría que realizar un data para recoger la información de las tres tablas.

Mi data no seria empleado,provincia,oficina sino tendría que recoger un data con:

> empleado,nombreProvincia,nombreOficina.

Seguiré buscando cual seria la mejor manera de hacerlo.

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo .

Comment: Si ejecutas native query te debe funcionar aunque no tengan relación.